# Cloudformation ECS / fargate - Run two containers in one task

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition, aws-cloudmap

I'm trying to run two containers in one task. The two containers must be resolvable using their DNS.

What I did ; I defined the two containers in the same task definition :

```
    MyTwoContainerTaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RuntimePlatform:
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: container1
          ...
        - Name: container2
          ...
...
```

And then I use two (one for each container) ServiceDiscovery resources and two Service resources to permit the DNS resolution :

```
  Container1CloudmapDiscoveryservice:
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
...
  Container1Service:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
    Properties:
      ServiceName: container1
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      TaskDefinition: !Ref MyTwoContainerTaskDefinition
      ServiceRegistries:
        - RegistryArn: !GetAtt Container1CloudmapDiscoveryservice.Arn
          Port: 7070
...
```

And the same resources for container 2.

The deployment is working but when I go to AWS portal I have two tasks that are containing the two containers.
I would like to have only one task containing my two containers.

Do you know if it's possible and what I'm missing ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple containers in one task definition. See here: [AWS ECS start multiple containers in one task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145233/aws-ecs-start-multiple-containers-in-one-task-definition)